# Undefined function 'imageSet' in matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying this code http://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab-computer-vision/725-feature-based-panoramic-image-stitching#7 but my matlab does not recognize the imageSet function. The error reads "Undefined function 'imageSet' for input arguments of
type 'char'.". I am not sure what is wrong I copied and pasted directly from the documentation.

Comment: `imageSet` is only available as of version `2014b`.  If you have older versions of MATLAB, then you won't be able to run any examples from the Computer Vision toolbox that require `imageSet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageSet` was added in the R2014b release. It is an object that gives you an easy way to get the paths of all the image files in directory. Think of it as a container of paths to images. You can modify the example to work with an older version of MATLAB by using a cell array of image file names instead of `imageSet`. However, there is always a chance that you may run into other new functions or objects.

There is also [a version of the image stitching example in the R2014a release](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014a/vision/examples/video-mosaicking.html).